# C++ macro - capitalize string

Tags: c++, macros

I'm using preprocessor macros to declare some repetitive variables, specifically:

```
QuitCallbackType quitCallback;
LossCallbackType lossCallback;
PauseCallbackType pauseCallback;
KeyCallbackType keyCallback;
MouseCallbackType mouseCallback;
```

I'd like to use a preprocessor macro to do it, a la

```
CREATE_CALLBACK_STORAGE(quit)
CREATE_CALLBACK_STORAGE(loss)
CREATE_CALLBACK_STORAGE(pause)
CREATE_CALLBACK_STORAGE(key)
CREATE_CALLBACK_STORAGE(mouse)
```

where it would essentially be like this:

```
#define CREATE_CALLBACK_STORAGE(x) capitalize(x)##CallbackType x##CallBack;
```

Is there a way to do this, so that I don't have to pass in both the capitalized AND lowercase versions of each name?

I realize it's not much less typing to use macros, but the problem itself began intriguing me.

Comment: A macro for such a simple naming scheme seems like it would be more confusing than helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The macro preprocessor doesn't have the ability to take substrings or capitalize a letter. Sorry.

If you could change your naming scheme you might have more success. For example:

```
QuitCallbackType _QuitCallback;
```

Edit: I've been warned not to use leading underscores, but the idea still applies:

```
QuitCallbackType callbackQuit;
```

Comment: +1 for the alternate scheme. In fact, if the OP is using a macro to define the variables, why not use another for accessing them too, say `#define CALLBACK(x) _##x##Callback`

Comment: @Mark: Names starting with underscore followed by uppercase letter, like `_QuitCallback` in your example, are reserved for the implementation, anywhere. That also goes for names with two successive underscores. By the way, since I commented on another answer of yours just half-hour or so ago, no I'm not "following" you. :-) I'll just delete this comment after ur edit. Cheers,

Comment: @Alf P. Steinbach: "By the way, since I commented on another answer of yours just half-hour or so ago, no I'm not "following" you." Excusatio non petita, accusatio manifesta. ;)

Comment: @Matteo: I just get this uncomfortable feeling when someone walking in front of me is going exactly where I'm going. Cheers,

Comment: @Alf: you're not alone, it often happens to me too. For the previous comment, just joking of course. :)

Comment: @Alf, I thought the reservation for underscores was only for two, not one. I see that the rules are more complicated than I remembered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier - thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should ditch the idea of macros altogether. A better solution would be to create a simple data structure, such as:

```
struct CallBacks {
  QuitCallbackType quit;
  LossCallbackType loss;
  PauseCallbackType pause;
  KeyCallbackType key;
  MouseCallbackType mouse;
};
```

And use this instead:

```
CallBacks callback;
```

You can only use the members you want:

```
callback.quit = GetCallback(...);
someFunc(callback.quit);
// ect..
```

It also makes the variable names (in my opinion) a little clearer.

Comment: How about using a union instead of a struct? A struct leads to excessive wasted memory, when all the data members are stored, and only one of them is used at any given time.